# How to create desktop shortcut for Firefox on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: firefox

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 and installed Firefox 79 from tar file. I can now only launch from command line. I would like to create shortcut and add it to my favorites. How can this be done?

I tried steps here https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-create-desktop-shortcut-launcher-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux but there is no Firefox file to copy, and there is no *.desktop file to be found anywhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create launchers on my desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop). *"there is no *.desktop file to be found anywhere."* - so make one!

Comment: Thanks @Nmath - it makes sense but there is no "Allow launching" option when I right click on the .desktop file.

Comment: Thanks for the link @Nmath - it didn't answer my question, but it did get me on the right path.

Comment: I've never seen "allow launching" as a context menu option, but it looks like you figured out that you need to make it **executable** = `chmod +x`

Answer (score 4):

There were several traps here to creating a working `firefox.desktop` file:

- "Allow launching" is not an option in Ubuntu 20.04.
- The `Exec=` value in the desktop file must contain the full path to the Firefox executable (e.g. `/home/wonko/myapps/firefox/firefox`) unless the executable is somewhere on the `$PATH` variable.
- The desktop file has to be placed in the `~/.local/share/applications/` directory.

Here is what I did without installing additional software, all from the command line:

1. [Optional] Download a Firefox icon from the interwebs and save it in `~/.local/share/icons/` with the name `firefox` and keep the existing file extension at the end (`.png`, `.ico`, `.svg`, etc). By using the original filename your themes are able to change the icon.
2. Create a `firefox.desktop` file at `~/.local/share/applications/`
3. Paste this into the file [change paths to suit your own config]:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
   [Desktop Entry]
   Type=Application
   Terminal=false
   Exec=/home/wonko/myapps/firefox/firefox
   Name=Firefox
   Comment=Firefox
   Icon=firefox
   Categories=GNOME;GTK;Network;WebBrowser;
   ```
4. Run `chmod +x ~/.local/share/applications/firefox.desktop`

After a few seconds, you should see the Firefox icon in your dock or application launcher and you're good to go. You can also launch by pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> and typing in "Firefox".

Answer (score 3):

Use the default `firefox.desktop` File,
Firefox is installed under snap. which means, /snap is the PATH to grab the Desktop file.

###### Find the correct Desktop file:

```
sudo find /snap/ -type f -name "firefox.desktop"
```

###### Example Output:

```
/snap/firefox/1232/firefox.desktop  
/snap/firefox/1232/meta/gui/firefox.desktop
```

We just found the `firefox.desktop` under the path: `/snap/firefox/1232/`.

###### Copy it to your Desktop:

```
cp -v /snap/firefox/1232/firefox.desktop ~/Desktop/
```

Then, Right Click on it and Allow Launching.

###### Fix Icon Doesn't Appear

If the Icon doesn't appear, You just need to add the full path for the image file.
**Note**: The snap PATH number `1232` might change over time, so we have to copy the icon image to a different location:

```
cp -v /snap/firefox/1232/default256.png /usr/share/pixmaps/firefox.png
```

Edit `firefox.desktop` from your Desktop, and change the line
From: `Icon=/default256.png`
To: `Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/firefox.png`